# Управление иерархией вложенности

Tags: c++

Существует базовый класс "модель некоторого устройства", в него включаются классы описывающие конфигурацию этого устройства.

```
Class Conf1
{
public:
Conf1(): Name("C1"){}

private:
string Name;
int mvalue;
}

Class Conf2 и Conf3 по подобию.

Class Model
{
public:
Model(): Name("M1"){}

private:    
string Name;
Conf1 c1;
Conf2 c2;
Conf3 c3;
}
```

Нужно каким-то образом устанавливать дочерность конфигураций по имени модели.

Все КОНФИГИ имеют "Имя" и "параметр", МОДЕЛЬ только "имя".
Нужно каким-то образом эти конфигурации закреплять за соответствующей моделью и производить вывод конфигураций данным образом.

```
<person> 
   <firstName>Иван</firstName> 
   <lastName>Иванов</lastName> 
   <phoneNumbers> 
       <phoneNumber>812 123-1234</phoneNumber>
       <phoneNumber>916 123-4567</phoneNumber>
   </phoneNumbers> 
</person>
```

Вывести я смогу, я не могу организовать иерархию вложенности классов.

Comment: "дочерность конфигураций" - это что, стеснюсь спросить?

Comment: То есть к модели M1 относятся именно такой набор конфигураций.
Что-то типо того нужно организовать:
<person>
  <firstName>Иван</firstName>
  <lastName>Иванов</lastName>
  <phoneNumbers>
    <phoneNumber>812 123-1234</phoneNumber>
    <phoneNumber>916 123-4567</phoneNumber>
  </phoneNumbers>
</person>

Вложенность, как в матрешке

Comment: не очень понятно, если честно. Ну сделайте метод класса Model, который будет возвращать его конфигурацию (конфигурации)

Comment: Нет, немного вы меня не поняли.
Пытаюсь переформулировать вопрос...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не очень понятно, что же Вам на самом деле нужно, поэтому попробую предположить...

Если Вы планируете добавлять классы "конфигурации", описывающие некое устройство, в класс "модель", но собираетесь делать это динамически, и на этапе создания класса "модель" еще не уверены в том, какие из классов-"конфигураций" будут туда включены,- создайте базовый класс для "конфигураций", а в классе "модель" используйте список, в который вы будете помещать экземпляры классов-"конфигураций", подходящих для описания этой "модели".

```
class BaseConfig {...}

class Config1 : public BaseConfig {...}
class Config2 : public BaseConfig {...}

class Model {
Model(): Name("M1"){}

...

private:
  list<BaseConfig> my_conf;
}
```

Пробегая по списку, можно будет выводить параметры классов-"конфигураций", если конечно не забыть переопределить для них оператор вывода.

> дочерность конфигураций по имени модели

Действительно, непонятно, что же Вы имели ввиду. Если Вы хотите определить, присутствует ли класс-"конфигурация" в некоторой "модели", то можно в классе-"конфигурации" реализовать метод возвращения имени(или, может, названия типа) "конфигурации", и, пробегаясь по списку в некоторой "модели", сравнивать возвращаемое этим методом значение с тем, которое интересует.

Comment: Сложно сформулировать задачу.
Она заключается в формировании контейнера, который содержит все конфигурационные объекты.
Этот контейнер унаследован от класса реализующего составную модель данных.
Класс составной модели унаследован от Класса предоставляющий интерфейс для модели данных.
С помощью этого интерфейса, этот контейнер можно воротить, как хотим. 
Как я понимаю это описано в протоколе Yang RFC 6020.
 
Ваш пример решения близок, все равно спасибо.